# Access violation and Abstract error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

I have a TButton event handler which either throws an Access Violation or Abstract Error when the method has completed execution. Delphi then highlights `end.` in my project source file. The method runs successfully, deleting the correct row from the database.

I have components which are created at runtime. Each row contains a label, an 'update' button and a 'delete' button, which have the database row number they are associated with in their names. The event handler throwing the errors is for delete.

```
procedure TFormInventoryMngmnt.ProductDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  button : TButton;
  row : integer;

  confirm : integer;
begin
  // Assuming it is button..how else can this be called?
  button := Sender as TButton;

  // Get row
  row := StrToInt(StringReplace(button.Name, 'Delete', '', [rfReplaceAll,  rfIgnoreCase]));

  // Confirm
  confirm := MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtInformation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0);
  if confirm = mrYes then
  begin
      // Delete row
      UnitSession.Query.SQL.Clear;
      UnitSession.Query.SQL.Add(Format(' DELETE FROM Products WHERE Product_ID = %s ', [IntToStr(row)]));
      UnitSession.Query.ExecSQL;
      buildManagementSection;
  end;

  // FIXME: why is this throwing access / abstract violation
end;
```

If you need more code or explanations just leave a comment and I'll get back to you.

Thanks!

**Updated with code for `buildManagementSection`**

I commented out the call to `buildManagementSection` from the listener and it did not throw any exceptions. This error could be caused from the method below, but I've never had a problem with it until now.

```
procedure TFormInventoryMngmnt.buildManagementSection;
var
  index : integer;
  runningHeight : integer;

  productName : TLabel;
  productUpdate : TButton;
  productDelete : TButton;
const
  MARGIN_TOP  = 35;

  // Left value of labels
  LABEL_LEFT  = 0;

  // Left value of update button
  UPDATE_LEFT = 235;

  // Left value of delete button
  DELETE_LEFT = 315;
begin
  // Run sql query
  UnitSession.Query.SQL.Clear;
  UnitSession.Query.SQL.Add('SELECT Product, Product_ID FROM Products ORDER BY Product_ID');
  UnitSession.Query.Active := true;

  // Remove all components in the manage section
  for index := (ScrollBoxManage.ComponentCount - 1) downto 0 do
  begin
      ScrollBoxManage.Components[index].Free;
  end;

  // No items
  if UnitSession.Query.RecordCount = 0 then
  begin
      productName            := TLabel.Create(ScrollBoxManage);
      productName.Parent     := ScrollBoxManage;
      productName.Caption    := 'No items!';
      productName.Font.Color := clRed;
      productName.Visible    := true;

      exit;
  end;

  // Build form
  UnitSession.Query.First;
  runningHeight := 0;
  for index := 0 to (UnitSession.Query.RecordCount - 1) do
  begin
      // Create components
      productName   := TLabel.Create(ScrollBoxManage);
      productUpdate := TButton.Create(ScrollBoxManage);
      productDelete := TButton.Create(ScrollBoxManage);

      // Set parents
      productName.Parent   := ScrollBoxManage;
      productUpdate.Parent := ScrollBoxManage;
      productDelete.Parent := ScrollBoxManage;

      // Set values
      productName.Caption   := UnitSession.Query.Fields[0].AsString;
      productUpdate.Caption := 'Update';
      productDelete.Caption := 'Delete';

      // Set event handlers
      productUpdate.OnClick := FormInventoryMngmnt.ProductUpdateClick;
      productDelete.OnClick := FormInventoryMngmnt.ProductDeleteClick;

      // Set top position
      productName.Top   := runningHeight + 3;
      productUpdate.Top := runningHeight;
      productDelete.Top := runningHeight;

      // Set button association
      productName.Name   := 'Label' + UnitSession.Query.Fields[1].AsString;
      productUpdate.Name := 'Update' + UnitSession.Query.Fields[1].AsString;
      productDelete.Name := 'Delete' + UnitSession.Query.Fields[1].AsString;

      // Set left position
      productName.Left   := LABEL_LEFT;
      productUpdate.Left := UPDATE_LEFT;
      productDelete.Left := DELETE_LEFT;

      // Set as visible
      productName.Visible   := true;
      productUpdate.Visible := true;
      productDelete.Visible := true;

      runningHeight := runningHeight + MARGIN_TOP;
      UnitSession.Query.Next;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: There's nothing there (in what you posted) that would generate an abstract error or AV as faar as I can see. What line is causing the exception? (A breakpoint on the `button := Sender as TButton;` line and then single-stepping through with F8 will tell you. If `Sender` is not a `TButton`, the `as TButton` will raise an invalid typecast exception.

Comment: Do you still get an AV or abstract error when clicking on the "No" button in the dialog box?

Comment: SSCCE, or it never happened

Comment: @KenWhite, is it not safe to assume that `Sender` will always be a TButton, as there is no other way the method is being called? I shall try your advice though.

Comment: @KeithMiller No, only when clicking "Yes". @KenWhite I tried single-stepping through, and it threw the AV at the `end;` of the procedure, then highlighted the `end.` of the project.

Comment: It's not safe to "assume"; you could accidentally assign the same handler to something not a button. However, I was pointing out that the only possible exception that I could see would be an invalid typecast raised by the `as` **if** it wasn't a `TButton`. If it's failing where you say it is, did it step into the `if confirm` block? If so, there are two possibilities: Either `UnitSession.Query` is nil (not yet created) or the exception is being raised in `buildManagementSection`. The first is easy to check by breaking on the first `UnitSection` line and evaluating it to see if it's nil. (more)

Comment: for casting you can also use 'Button:=TButton(Sender);' what does 'buildManagementSection;' do? I realy don't know how is the other part of the code. but you may free the button object two times. for instance the buildmanagementSection I guess free the button and then update something like onDataChange of a datasource that it want to free the button again. and it may cause that error. check who is freeing the button.

Comment: The second means setting a breakpoint on `buildManagementSection`;  when it hits, hit F7 to step into it, and then F8 through the code there to see which line throws the exception.

Comment: @Loghman: The way being used in the post is *far safer* than a direct typecast, which can succeed even if the `Sender` is not a `TButton` and make things worse. Bad advice.

Comment: 'it threw the AV at the end; of the procedure' - where it started to clean temporary string variables... try declaring them explicitly: str1 := StringReplace... and str2:= Format(... and then clear them to empty values before the procedure end;

Comment: To avoid the possible typecast exception you could also use `if Sender  is TButton then ....` in this case only Senders that are TButtons or classes that are parents of TButton are handled. All other senders are ignored.

Comment: I find `Format('%s', [IntToStr(row)])` to be rather quaint. You mean `Format('%d', [row])`

Comment: @RFerwerda: He's not getting an invalid typecast error. :) Your suggestion is good, but there's a problem: You have to also add an additional line of code: `button := TButton(Sender);` or (somewhat redundant) `button := Sender as TButton;`. It also forces you to wrap the entire procedure inside an `if..end` starting with that `if`, because if you don't all other code would use an unassigned `button` variable. I'd rather use the `as` case, where anything other than a `TButton` would raise an exception, because the code is written only to handle the button.

Comment: @David: Better would be `WHERE ProductID = :ID`, and then a `Query.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := row;`.

Comment: Given that the code throws "random" errors (AV and abstract), it seems likely that you are either accessing a freed object, or an unassigned object. I would suggest using FastMM4 in full debug mode if possible.

Comment: @KenWhite, I know he isn't getting that specific error. But isn't stackoverflow also a place to just help each other getting even better code instead of only solving the problems? I'm also aware that the whole procedure must be inside the if, I thought that would be clear enough for all of us :) The `as` solution could also do, but I always favor code which won't raise exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

The button instance hasn't been created!

There is no need to say

```
button := Sender as Tbutton
```

just reference the original button in the code since it is in scope on the form

```
row := StrToInt(StringReplace(ProductDelete.Name, 'Delete', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
```

or do this

```
with TButton(sender) do
row := StrToInt(StringReplace(Name, 'Delete', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
```

Or if you really want to do it this way, with a variable holding the button instance, then
you must create it first

```
begin
  button := TButton.Create(Self);
  try
    button := TButton(Sender)
    // your code
  finally
    button.Free
  end
end
```

Comment: No, you don't. If the button is on the form, and the event is attached to the button, the `Sender` is the button, and the code will work just fine. If the button wasn't created, the cast of `Sender as TButton` would raise an exception. (Also, you wouldn't `Create` a button and toss it - memory leak.) Using `Sender` allows you to easily extend the code to also handle a speedbutton or menu item that can invoke the same code. (Of course, then you wouldn't use `Sender as TButton`, but would instead use `if Sender is TButton` so you could collect information and then run the rest of the code.

Comment: The button is created within `buildManagementSection` where this method is assigned to its `OnClick` property.

Comment: @Ken White Your comment to my posting was unnecessarily critical and included changing the subject for no good reason. My answer contained valid options to the problem of the AV.

Comment: @JaredG Of course, that wasn't obvious to me initially. Looking at it now, it is obvious to me that if you're creating a button in that button's own onclick event handler, that something's going to fall apart in a hurry.

Comment: @Freddie: No, your answer is wrong. The button exists, because if it didn't it can't be in `Sender`. Creating a new one to throw it away to assign an existing one to the same var is a mem leak (and the `Free` at the end frees the button on the form itself, not the one you've created - you've thrown that one away with the assignment of the form's button; now you've caused a new problem.  The blind cast with `TButton(Sender)` causes an AV if `Sender` happens *not* to be a `TButton`. Your answer is wrong. There's nothing unnecessarily critical; your answer was wrong, and I explained why.

Comment: In addition, the line using `Sender.Name` won't even compile, because `Sender` is a `TObject`, and there is no `Name` property for a `TObject`. That isn't introduced until further in the  inheritance chain (`TComponent`, IIRC). So in those two lines of code you have a potential AV and code that won't even compile in the first place.

Comment: The only mistake I made in the code above has now been corrected. The rest of it has been tested in an actual project and suffers from none of the maladys that Key White claims it does. The response does however not form an answer to the original question.

Comment: @Freddie - Your actual project creates buttons which it never uses.

Comment: @Sertac I'm gonna go eat worms now.

Comment: @Freddie - Please don't do that! :) Well, nobody's against you. It's just that no one is able to tell you how wrong your last snippet is. It creates a button that no one ever cares or use, and frees the button that is the sender.

Comment: @Sertac I _could_ go into a long description of what I intended (good intentions incidentally) by my answer, but since no one really understands it at all, I'm just going to go eat worms.